# Decreasing the pixel ratio for an embedded google map (phonegap - android hybrid app)

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, hybrid, pixel-ratio

I've been developing an app which presents a google map for the user,
this app should run on samsung S2, S3 and S4.

This means device pixel ratios of 1.5, 2.0 and 3.0, which results in a problem :
while on the samsung S2 the street names are big enough to be readable,
the S3 and S4 present the map in a very dense manner (graphically speaking),
this makes the map (both street graphics and street names to be almost illegible).

Has anyone encountered this problem, and would possibly know how to overcome it ?

Sincerely.

Comment: Do you see the same problem in Google Maps application on these devices?

Comment: No - the google maps present a map with resolution which is a bit higher from the one in my app.

any thoughts ?

Comment: But I don't think that it matter because the maps api I'm using is v3, and the google app on the phone is the new google maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution I've implemented was to decrease the app's resolution -
just for the map screen, then increase it back to its original value.

Is this the best way of solving this issue in your opinion ?

please leave your reasoned comments so that others could learn as well :)